# Exceptions in Google Cloud Dataflow pipelines from BigQuery to Cloud Bigtable

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

Executing DataFlow pipelines, every once in a while we see those Exceptions. Is there anything we can do about them? We have a quite simple flow that reads data from a BigQuery query and populate data in BigTable.

Also what happens to data inside the pipeline? Is it reprocessed? Or is it lost in transit to BigTable?

```
 CloudBigtableIO.initializeForWrite(p);
     p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(getQuery()))
     .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Mutation>() {
           public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
             Mutation output = convertDataToRow(c.element());
             c.output(output);
           }

           }))
         .apply(CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config));


private static Mutation convertDataToRow(TableRow element) {
     LOG.info("element: "+ element);
     LOG.info("BASM_segment_id: "+ element.get("BASM_segment_id"));
     if(element.get("BASM_AID") != null){
         Put obj = new Put(getRowKey(element).getBytes()).addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, SEGMENT_COLUMN_NAME, ((String)element.get("BAS_category")).getBytes() );
                obj.addColumn(USER_FAMILY, "AID".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BASM_AID")).getBytes());
         if(element.get("BASM_segment_id") != null){
                obj.addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, "segment_id".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BASM_segment_id")).getBytes());
         }
         if(element.get("BAS_sub_category") != null){
                obj.addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, "sub_category".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BAS_sub_category")).getBytes());
         }
         if(element.get("BAS_name") != null){
                obj.addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, "name".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BAS_name")).getBytes());
         }
         if(element.get("BAS_description") != null){
                obj.addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, "description".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BAS_description")).getBytes());
         }
         if(element.get("BAS_last_compute_day") != null){obj.addColumn(USER_FAMILY, "Krux_User_id".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BASM_krux_user_id")).getBytes());
                obj.addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, "last_compute_day".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BAS_last_compute_day")).getBytes());
         }
         if(element.get("BAS_type") != null){
                obj.addColumn(SEGMENT_FAMILY, "type".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BAS_type")).getBytes());
         }      
         if(element.get("BASM_REGID") != null){
                obj.addColumn(USER_FAMILY, "REGID".getBytes(), ((String)element.get("BASM_REGID")).getBytes() );
         }
        return obj;
     }else{
         return null;
     }
    }
```

Following is the exception which we are getting:

> 2016-08-22T21:47:33.469Z: Error:   (84707221e08b977b): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeExc
>   ption: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: StatusRuntimeException: 1 time,
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:162)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449)
>           at com.nytimes.adtech.dataflow.pipelines.BigTableSegmentData$2.processElement(BigTableSegmentData.java:70)
>   Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsExcept
>   on: Failed 1 action: StatusRuntimeException: 1 time,
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:35)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrapIf(UserCodeException.java:40)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.wrapUserCodeException(DoFnRunnerBase.java:368)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:51)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.
>   ava:47)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449)
>           at com.nytimes.adtech.dataflow.pipelines.BigTableSegmentData$2.processElement(BigTableSegmentData.java:70)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.
>   ava:47)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:226)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:167)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:71)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:288)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:221)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by:

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: StatusRuntimeException: 1 time,
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.handleExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:389)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.mutate(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:274)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$CloudBigtableSingleTableBufferedWriteFn.processElement(CloudBigtabl
>   IO.java:966)

Exception copied from Dataflow console

```
(7e75740160102c05): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: StatusRuntimeException: 1 time, at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:162) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449) at com.nytimes.adtech.dataflow.pipelines.BigTableSegmentData$2.processElement(BigTableSegmentData.java:70) Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: StatusRuntimeException: 1 time, at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:35) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrapIf(UserCodeException.java:40) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.wrapUserCodeException(DoFnRunnerBase.java:368) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:51) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449) at com.nytimes.adtech.dataflow.pipelines.BigTableSegmentData$2.processElement(BigTableSegmentData.java:70) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:226) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:167) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:71) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:288) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:221) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: StatusRuntimeException: 1 time, at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.handleExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:389) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.mutate(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:274) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$CloudBigtableSingleTableBufferedWriteFn.processElement(CloudBigtableIO.java:966)
```

2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop....
 2016-08-23 (13:17:54) java.lang.RuntimeException:

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version of the client are you using? 0.9.1?

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel yes we are using 0.9.1 version for bigtable-hbase-dataflow

Comment: I've asked someone in engineering to comment - it should be later today.

Comment: Can you search your logs for "exceptions occured during a bulk operation" (sic)?  That should give more informative logging about the real problem.  RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException is too generic.

Comment: You may want to consider: if (output != null) { c.output(output); };  This type of exception can occur with null values.

Comment: Hi Amandeep - can you email me your projectID?  lesv (at) g...le

Comment: @SolomonDuskis I can not see such entries in my log "exception occured during a bulk operations" but yes i am trying to process around 9643753841 rows.                                                                                                                I have also updated the question with logs copied from Dataflow console.

Comment: Hi @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel, I can provide you my projectId but for that I need your email id which is not readable in the comments

Comment: Feel free to email me the projectId.  My address can be found at: https://github.com/sduskis

Comment: @SolomonDuskis I have sent an email containing Project details to your email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We spoke offline.  The problem here is that you have too many Dataflow workers compared to the number of Cloud Bigtable nodes in your cluster.  You need to change that ratio by either [reducing Dataflow workers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc) or contacting our team to increase your Cloud Bigtable resources.

Bigtable was performing admirably relative to the amount of Cloud Bigtable Nodes you had, but the load from Dataflow was too high to reliably handle.

You can view your usage in the ["CPU Usage"](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/monitoring-instance) graph in the Google Cloud console.  Anything over 80% of your capacity is likely to cause problems.  If you get more Bigtable Quota, you can increase the number of nodes you have before you run the Dataflow job, and reduce it after the job is done.  For example, [Scio does that](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/7cb2aecca41fc828f7f8bbb912fdbb2b973c7f49/scio-bigtable/src/main/java/com/spotify/scio/bigtable/BigtableUtil.java#L40).

==

Regarding "Also what happens to data inside the pipeline? Is it reprocessed? Or is it lost in transit to BigTable?":

Dataflow tries to send the data to Bigtable again.  In those cases, Dataflow's retry mechanism will correct for temporary issues.

Unfortunately, when the problem turns out to be Cloud Bigtable overload, the retries compound the problem by sending more traffic to Bigtable, thereby exacerbating the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Solomon Duskis, I have reduced the number of workers now I can't see the exception which is coming before but obviously, my job is now taking more time to complete.

Comment: Yup.  Reducing the workers will do that.  I took a quick look at your charts, and it looks like you can add a couple more workers.

Alternatively, you can ask us to increase your quota, and add more Bigtable nodes before you start your Dataflow, and reduce the number after you finish.  The more Bigtable nodes, the more throughput you can do, and the faster your job will complete.